# Profile face TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

My goal is get such head drawing: http://www.shutterstock.com/pic.mhtml?id=87217450

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Can you please at least show us some attempts to get that drawing? We certainly cannot draw from scracth for you but we can only help you about the specific points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can buy the image from shutterstock.com and then use a vector drawing program, e.g. [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), to trace the image. There is a tutorial on how to trace an image in Inkscape [here](http://inkscape.org/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html). (You may want to try this out on a different image from e.g. Google Images before buying the picture).

As an example, I did it for this picture:

[image]

I've taken the following steps:

- Import the picture into Inkscape using File > Import
- Trace the image by selecting it and then using Path > Trace bitmap; use Color Quantization, with 2 colors (the 2 colors will be black and white)
- You now have two objects: the original bitmap and the traced vector version of it. Delete the bitmap by selecting it and pressing `Delete`.
- Now save the file as a pdf file

Alternatively use [inkscape2tikz](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/) to export to a TikZ file. This plugin has to be installed manually (see webpage for instructions, it's pretty easy). Here is the resulting TikZ code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt,x=0.80pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-50.506837,-386.18185)}]
  \path[fill=black] (50.5068,576.1819) -- (50.5068,386.1819) --
    (250.5068,386.1819) -- (450.5068,386.1819) -- (450.5068,576.1819) --
    (450.5068,766.1819) -- (250.5068,766.1819) -- (50.5068,766.1819) --
    (50.5068,576.1819) -- cycle(402.8611,757.1819) .. controls (402.5268,746.8633)
    and (392.4931,732.3671) .. (380.1653,724.3923) .. controls (367.6261,716.2807)
    and (355.2188,710.3335) .. (340.0454,705.1615) .. controls (321.5600,698.8605)
    and (315.9828,696.2332) .. (310.0993,691.0543) .. controls (301.1418,683.1696)
    and (300.0395,677.0052) .. (305.8705,667.4063) .. controls (307.8705,664.1140)
    and (309.5068,660.6485) .. (309.5068,659.7053) .. controls (309.5068,656.7466)
    and (306.2499,652.3181) .. (303.1206,651.0218) .. controls (298.0029,648.9020)
    and (293.5068,644.2933) .. (293.5068,641.1671) .. controls (293.5068,638.4185)
    and (295.0541,636.7164) .. (301.9444,631.8852) .. controls (305.3755,629.4794)
    and (305.1734,627.7921) .. (301.0804,624.6701) .. controls (297.3120,621.7959)
    and (293.3374,614.7869) .. (294.2005,612.5378) .. controls (294.5023,611.7513)
    and (296.1572,610.3867) .. (297.8780,609.5053) .. controls (301.7954,607.4989)
    and (302.4724,606.4733) .. (302.4915,602.5164) .. controls (302.5044,599.8383)
    and (301.4677,598.4609) .. (295.7568,593.5692) .. controls (283.2017,582.8149)
    and (280.5068,579.9169) .. (280.5068,577.1694) .. controls (280.5068,573.9916)
    and (282.7993,570.3501) .. (298.4405,548.6818) .. controls (305.1898,539.3318)
    and (311.5830,529.9785) .. (312.6477,527.8966) .. controls (316.0849,521.1754)
    and (319.5193,502.8819) .. (321.0201,483.3004) .. controls (321.8783,472.1043)
    and (323.2003,462.0906) .. (324.3364,458.1818) .. controls (328.2444,444.7354)
    and (333.5006,431.7971) .. (336.2246,428.9184) .. controls (340.0429,424.8834)
    and (350.4362,417.5316) .. (355.1326,415.5437) .. controls (366.0610,410.9178)
    and (389.5546,403.8016) .. (402.9251,401.0675) .. controls (416.8273,398.2246)
    and (429.5068,393.9720) .. (429.5068,392.1523) .. controls (429.5068,391.7362)
    and (428.7950,391.1227) .. (427.9251,390.7888) .. controls (425.8696,390.0001)
    and (75.7121,390.0201) .. (72.7681,390.8092) .. controls (66.8348,392.3995)
    and (76.4963,396.3645) .. (97.0047,400.7558) .. controls (122.0432,406.1171)
    and (145.3049,414.3126) .. (154.5068,421.0149) .. controls (164.6499,428.4027)
    and (166.1709,430.7383) .. (172.3465,448.4095) .. controls (176.5569,460.4572)
    and (177.8433,467.9324) .. (179.0187,487.1819) .. controls (179.8469,500.7465)
    and (183.8819,521.0150) .. (186.9653,527.0998) .. controls (188.2944,529.7229)
    and (194.2263,538.5769) .. (200.1471,546.7754) .. controls (220.3958,574.8138)
    and (221.2221,576.3461) .. (218.2187,580.2898) .. controls (217.5453,581.1741)
    and (212.9471,585.3638) .. (208.0005,589.6002) .. controls (203.0540,593.8367)
    and (198.4339,598.3932) .. (197.7336,599.7257) .. controls (195.8200,603.3672)
    and (197.1516,606.6139) .. (201.5793,609.1024) .. controls (204.3602,610.6654)
    and (205.5068,611.9772) .. (205.5068,613.5958) .. controls (205.5068,616.2778)
    and (200.4640,623.5993) .. (197.5382,625.1651) .. controls (194.1312,626.9885)
    and (195.0666,629.9652) .. (199.9791,632.9325) .. controls (208.6744,638.1846)
    and (208.3340,644.0049) .. (199.0242,649.2590) .. controls (189.4525,654.6610)
    and (188.3890,658.4503) .. (193.9812,667.2282) .. controls (200.1993,676.9884)
    and (197.8828,685.1211) .. (186.6381,693.0088) .. controls (180.4385,697.3576)
    and (174.3132,699.9695) .. (156.9310,705.6764) .. controls (145.5012,709.4290)
    and (134.2412,714.8587) .. (121.3417,722.8380) .. controls (114.7942,726.8881)
    and (111.0765,730.0605) .. (107.0895,734.9997) .. controls (100.5632,743.0847)
    and (96.5068,751.8277) .. (96.5068,757.8095) -- (96.5068,762.1883) --
    (249.7568,761.9351) -- (403.0068,761.6819) -- (402.8611,757.1819) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, all I can see in the picture is a vase...

Comment: The image in the question is sold in vector format (as an eps) so tracing isn't necessary for this one.  So I think you should say that *if* the image is bitmap you can trace it, otherwise just import it into Inkscape as-is.  What did you do with the Inkscape file?  Did you convert it to TikZ (as the tags on the question imply it should have been)?

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Perhaps I misunderstood his question. I didn't do anything with the Inkscape file, I just saved it as pdf. Maybe the [inkscape2tikz](https://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/) Inkscape plugin could be of help here. But I don't see the point: it'd make ugly code, so one may just as well include the pdf file.

Comment: @Yori I don't think you misunderstood the question (not that I'd call it a very clear question!).  What I wanted was to better understand the steps you went through - there were a few missing pieces which could have been done in a variety of ways.  I don't mean to imply that you should have done them in a particular way, just that as it stands it's unclear what you did from your answer.

Comment: Given the fact that the image just consists of a shape with lots of points and support points, I'd say the code generated by `inkscape2tikz` isn't too bad. How else could this image be represented in TikZ code?

Comment: @Jake: yes, I agree. I would just save it as a pdf file and use `includegraphics`.